# fetch always pass with OPTIONS method

Tags: reactjs, cors, flask-restplus

I made API server with flask-restplus.

Also use cors module for avoid CSP issue.

And frontend is React.js.

My code is here.

```
class ArticleList(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print(1)
        return {"status":"true", "result":"article write success"}, 200
```

React.js code is here.

```
_writeArticle = () => {
    const { title, body, tags, password } = this.state;
    const data = {title: title, body: body, tags: tags, password: password};
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/article/", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: data
    })
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I defined method to `POST`. But, it request with `OPTIONS` method.

After searched in google, that issue cause by CORS.

So I defined cors to main code like this.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from api.board import ArticleList, Article
from flask_restplus import cors

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.decorators=[cors.crossdomain(origin='*')]

api.add_resource(ArticleList, '/article')
api.add_resource(Article, '/article/<int:article_no>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But it still request with `OPTIONS`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is the browser who make this option request, and it's for security.
You have to change the server to an state which accept option request.

Comment: when the browser make a options request, you need to ensure your server returns 200 ok and set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header appropriately in response header. You cannot bypass the options request since it is automatically made by the browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `OPTIONS` request is called `pre-flight request`.
Under some circumstances relating to `CORS` the web browser will first send a `pre-flight request` to server to check if your domain is allowed to make requests to the server or not. If the server says `yes` then your actual `POST` request will be sent. Otherwise, no additional requests will be sent and the web browser will spit an error at you.

Here is documentation on `pre-flight request`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#preflight-requests

And according to the documentation:

> The pre-flight request uses the HTTP OPTIONS method.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution,

```
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with supporting information and explanation for how this answers the question